# Azure Policy to allow only lowercase string

Tags: azure, naming, policy

I am planning to achieve the below naming pattern in Azure using a policy.

```
tstpaas-appName-Env-Serial
```

- `tstpaas` is a string constant
- `appname` can be string with length of 3-5 characters
- `env` - dev/ust/prd
- `serial` - three numbers

**Example:**

```
tstpaas-app-dev-001
```

All of the characters should be lower case. I am able to match the pattern, however, allowing 3-5 characters for app name and allowing only lower case values is not working. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Here is my policy:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "in": "[parameters('allowedResourceTypes')]"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "not": {
                "field": "name",
                "match": "[parameters('nameMatchPattern1')]"
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "value": "[if(greaterOrEquals(length(field('name')), 18), substring(field('name'), 14, 3), 'not in allowed values')]",
                "in": "[parameters('allowedEnvironments')]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "nameMatchPattern1": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "nameMatchPattern1",
        "description": "Pattern to match for names. Cna include ? and # for digits and letters"
      }
    },
    "allowedResourceTypes": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "allowedResourceTypes",
        "description": "List of resource types, for which policy applies"
      }
    },
    "allowedEnvironments": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed Environments",
        "description": "The list of Environments"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "dev",
        "int",
        "uat",
        "prd"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Parameter for `namematchpatter` is:

```
tstpaas-?????-???-###
```